# So where is the sencha sdk anyways?

Tags: extjs

I have sencha installed on my system and my company has purchased a license and support (I wish they'd let me know how to access this support) but thankfully there are places like Stackover flow :)

I am trying to follow a simple tutorial (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/getting_started/getting_started.html) and I cannot get past the first step which is to generate an app with `sencha` so I do this ...

```
 [red@tools-dev1 ~]$ cd TutApp/
 [red@tools-dev1 TutApp]$ pwd
 /users/red/TutApp
 [red@tools-dev1 TutApp]$ which sencha
 /scratch/sencha/Sencha/Cmd/5.1.3.61/sencha
 [red@tools-dev1 TutApp]$ sencha -sdk /scratch/sencha/Sencha generate app TutorialApp ./TutorialApp
 Sencha Cmd v5.1.3.61
 [ERR] Unable to locate supported Framework.

       Please ensure this command was executed from a supported framework
       directory or that a framework directory was specified via the -sdk switch.
       For example:

           sencha -sdk /path/to/framework-dir generate app AppName path/to/app

 [ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExState: Not a framework directory : /scratch/sencha/Sencha
      at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand$Property.set(AbstractCommand.java:406)
      at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.processConfigParam(AbstractCommand.java:527)
      at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.configure(AbstractCommand.java:114)
      at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:129)
    Caused by: Not a framework directory : /scratch/sencha/Sencha
      at com.sencha.command.Sencha.setSdkPath(Sencha.java:388)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
      at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand$Property.set(AbstractCommand.java:394)
      at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.processConfigParam(AbstractCommand.java:527)
      at com.sencha.cli.AbstractCommand.configure(AbstractCommand.java:114)
      at com.sencha.command.Sencha.main(Sencha.java:129)
```

OK what do I use for `/path/to/framework-dir`???

Comment: What do you mean by "sencha installed on your system"? Is that Sencha Cmd? If so, then what is in "/scratch/sencha/Sencha"?

Comment: I was finally able to figure out what my `framework-dir` is on my system: `/scratch/sencha/Sencha/Complete/1.0.5.1/ext-4.2.2.1144/` Too bad it wasn't named `/scratch/sencha/Sencha/Complete/1.0.5.1/framework-dir-4.2.2.1144/`  them maybe I wouldn't have to guess.

Comment: The tutorial doesn't say "framework-dir", it says "/path/to/framework". Not really sure how it could be much clearer.

Comment: So, what is the solution? I am a complete noob and tried this https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/guides/getting_started/getting_started.html but I do not know where is the `path/to/framework` after installation of `sencha-cmd`.

Comment: I gave up on sencha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much like any other SDK or set of tools you might download from a company, "where" is completely dependent on the folder you chose to download and extract them to.

Your confusion may come from the fact that *Sencha Cmd* and the *Sencha framework* are different downloads -- and because *Sencha Cmd* is a binary program physically installed on your machine, whereas the SDK/framework is simply a folder containing static files.

When *Sencha Cmd* is installed, you can find it's location (on Unix/Linux) by typing `which sencha` into your terminal.

The SDK/framework is more tricky to find, again because it's just a regular folder containing static assets. Seasoned developers tend to stick all SDKs in the same place (so they don't have to wonder *"WTF did I put that?"*) but not everyone does exactly the same thing.

In the Sencha ecosystem, I'm willing to bet most people don't install *Sencha Cmd* and the SDK/framework in the same place -- again because of the nature of binary-vs-static-assets.

Answer (score 1):

Well it took me ages to work out what was meant by -sdk too. It isn't at all obvious because most of us amateur developers don't think of the [Ext JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_JS) framework download as an sdk. This worked for me on windows (forgive me!), using `wamp`.

Open a dos box and navigate to the sencha cmd dir, in my case:

```
C:\Users\csheen\bin\Sencha\Cmd\6.0.2.14>
```

then typed the following command string:

```
sencha -sdk c:\wamp\www\ext-6.0.0 generate app MyApp c:\wamp\www\myapp
```

Answer (score 1):

@arghurakay, @Ozgur, and @jsalisbury are absoluterly correct. 
This is what I did:

1. Download and install sencha cmd
2. Make sure that the sencha cmd is in the Environment variable list after the installation
3. If you can't find the variable, manually add the variable to your list. (I had to do this)
4. Download the sdk as a zip file and unzip it to c:\Path\To\Framework
5. Run the command sencha -sdk c:\Path\To\Framework\ext-6.0.0 generate app MyApp c:\Path\To\myapp
6. **cmd was throwing an error that framework folder is not valid and then I realized there are some spaces in my directory's name.**